# Notepad: How to prefix each line with the last line that contains a string?

Tags: notepad++

I'm working with chat logs and want to format them.

They look exactly like this, including the # symbols:

```
Tuesday, February 24, 2015
##Person1 (21:22:01): hello
##Person2 (21:22:37): hi
Wednesday, February 25, 2015
##Person1 (13:12:43): hey
##Person2 (13:13:04): hey
```

The date is only posted for each new day, and I'd like it to be formatted something like this, so it's workable in a spreadsheet:

```
Tuesday, February 24, 2015
Tuesday, February 24, 2015##Person1 (21:22:01): hey
Tuesday, February 24, 2015##Person2 (21:22:37): hi
Wednesday, February 25, 2015
Wednesday, February 25, 2015##Person1 (13:12:43): hey
Wednesday, February 25, 2015##Person2 (13:13:04): hey
```

After that, I can easily delete the lines that don't contain the ## string to get rid of the date-only lines.

Is there any way to get Notepad++ to add the entire, most recent line that contains a string from the date (like `\d{1,2}, 201\d{1}$`), to the beginning of each line underneath it (up until the next instance)?

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be done in Notepad++. A small script could do the job. I can give you a perl script if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this can't be done in Notepad++.

Here is perl one-liner that does the job.

```
perl -ane '$date = $1 if /^(\w+,\h+\w+\h+\d\d?,\h+20\d\d)/;s/^(?=##)/$date/ && print;' file.txt
```

If you want to replace the file inplace, use:

```
perl -i -ane '$date = $1 if /^(\w+,\h+\w+\h+\d\d?,\h+20\d\d)/;s/^(?=##)/$date/ && print;' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
Tuesday, February 24, 2015##Person1 (21:22:01): hello
Tuesday, February 24, 2015##Person2 (21:22:37): hi
Wednesday, February 25, 2015##Person1 (13:12:43): hey
Wednesday, February 25, 2015##Person2 (13:13:04): hey
```

**Regex Explanation:**

```
/               # delimiter
  ^             # beginning of line
  (             # start group 1
    \w+         # 1 or more word character
    ,           # a comma
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    \w+         # 1 or more word character
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    \d\d?       # 1 or 2 digits
    ,           # a comma
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    20\d\d      # 20 and 2 digits
  )             # end group 1
/               # delimiter


s/              # substitute, delimiter
  ^             # beginning of line
  (?=##)        # positive lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we have ## at the beginning
/               # delimiter
  $date         # the date found with the preceding  regex
/               # delimiter
```